# How to define a multi-dimensional array in a unix shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sh, ksh

How can I implement a multi-dimensional array in a unix shell script?
The solution should not only work for bash but as well for other unix shells.

There is a similar question specific for bash. I posted the same answer there, but I wanted to re-ask the question in a more generic way so that not only users looking for a bash solution get the answer.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian The FAQ [explicitly encourages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) such self-answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

Independent of the shell being used (sh, ksh, bash, ...) the following approach works pretty well for n-dimensional arrays (the sample covers a 2-dimensional array).

In the sample the line-separator (1st dimension) is the space character. For introducing a field separator (2nd dimension) the standard unix tool `tr` is used. Additional separators for additional dimensions can be used in the same way.

Of course the performance of this approach is not very well, but if performance is not a criteria this approach is quite generic and can solve many problems:

```sh
array2d="1.1:1.2:1.3 2.1:2.2 3.1:3.2:3.3:3.4"

function process2ndDimension {
    for dimension2 in $*
    do
        echo -n $dimension2 "   "
    done
    echo
}

function process1stDimension {
    for dimension1 in $array2d
    do
        process2ndDimension `echo $dimension1 | tr : " "`
    done
}

process1stDimension
```

The output of that sample looks like this:

```
1.1     1.2     1.3     
2.1     2.2     
3.1     3.2     3.3     3.4
```